# Escaping two dollar signs at once

Tags: bash

I have an SQL statement which I am running in my Bash script. It contains instances of two dollar signs in a row, for example:

```
psql -U $username -h $DATABASE_HOST $DATABASE_NAME -c "DO $$ DECLARE myVar varchar; END$$"
```

How can both of these be escaped?

Comment: `\$$` ought to do it as long as there are no alphanumeric characters following the second one.

Comment: …and quote your variables!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put a backslash in front of each one:

```
psql -U "$username" -h "$DATABASE_HOST" "$DATABASE_NAME" -c \
  "DO \$\$ DECLARE myVar varchar; END\$\$"
```

(Actually, since the second `$` is followed by white space, the shell won't try to expand it, but the second backslash doesn't hurt).

Or, use single quotes around the string so that it is interpreted literally by the shell:

```
psql -U "$username" -h "$DATABASE_HOST" "$DATABASE_NAME" -c \
  'DO $$ DECLARE myVar varchar; END$$'
```

Like [Biffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418066/biffen) said in the comments, it's a good habit to always quote your variables.

If you're finding that the `$$` is still being expanded, then I guess that this code is being parsed twice. In that case, you will need to either double-escape (`\\\$\\\$`) inside double quotes, or use `\$\$` inside single quotes (or better yet, avoid parsing it twice if you don't need to).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Getting the following error:

LINE 1: DO 21563 DECLARE

Comment: Is this whole thing inside some other double quotes, or a heredoc, or something else?

Comment: Ah, apologies. Yes in order for the script results to go into a variable its wrapped in ``. I've realised now I can just put double slashes before each $. Thanks again.